# DE Mixture Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, mixing, concentration-of-measure

**Suppose a tank with a total capacity of 60 Gallons is currently only half full of a solution of water with 2% bleach concentration.  At time t=0 water with a bleach concentration of 7% is pumped in at a rate of 2 gallons per minute.  Water is drained from the tank at a rate of 1 gallon per minute.  When the tank is full, everything shuts off.  What is the amount of bleach in the tank at this time, and what is the concentration?**

*I don't need it worked out I just want to know if I set this up right. let me know what i need to add or change anything.*

> dA/dt = (2)(.07)-(1)(A/30+t)

Comment: Looks good to me.  If you have to solve it then you will need to write down an initial condition too.

Comment: yeah in this case that would be A(0)=.6 right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Now when I solve for t when the tank is 60 gallons i get 827.89 mins which seems to much for me i would think it takes 30 mins to fill up the rest of the tank. 2 gallons/min (pumped in) and 1 gallon/min (pumped out) which means getting 1 gallon/min so 30 mins

Comment: Not sure what you mean "solve for $t$", the time taken is $30$ minutes, exactly as you said in the middle of your comment.  And the question asks you to find $A$ when the tank is full, not $t$.

Comment: well even so i should get 30 mins if i solve for t correct? when i get the function A(t) i set it equal to 60 (A(t)=60) and solve for t I should still get 30 mins.

Comment: I thought $ \ A(t) \ $ represented your "mass of bleach" function.  You have an unstated "volume in tank" function $ \ V(t) \ = \ 30 + (2 - 1) t \ $ , which you used correctly in constructing your "outgoing fluid" term.  It is _that_ which you would use to solve $ \ V(T) \ = \ 30 + T \ = \ 60 \ . $  Otherwise, your statements look to be correct -- and you now have a differential equation which is not separable and requires the use of an "integrating factor".

Comment: Okay thank you i guess i was a bit confused on what A(t) actually stood for

Answer (score 0):

How much bleach is lost in dt?

-C/Vdt

Where C is the current amount of bleach and V is the current volume.

How much bleach is added in dt?

0.07*2*dt

So:

dC/dt = 0.07*2-C/V

And V = 30+t

Describes the amount of bleach in the tank, with the appropriate initial conditions

And you just need it at the time when the tank is full.

eta: I guess your answer is right up to missing parentheses